# Bentley-Ottmann algorithm for two groups of lines segments

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, line-intersection

The Bentley-Ottmann algorithm is used for the computation of intersection of line segments.

However, instead of finding the intersecting points of all the lines among themselves, I want to find the intersecting points between two groups of lines. This is to say that for every line in line group `A`, I want to know the intersection points between those lines and the lines in group `B`.

Is there anyway I can extend the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) for this? I already have the existing Bentley-Ottmann algorithm implemented ( [in the library of CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/Sweep_line_2/Chapter_main.html)), and I am not keen to modify it. I am, however, am keen to find ways to reuse it and extend it.

**Edit: Any other algorithms ( not necessarily based on Bentley- Ottmann) are welcome. It would be better if those algorithms are already implemented in the existing library.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find all intersections between all lines in `A+B`, then remove intersections between lines in the same set. You're not increasing the complexity by much and this allows you to use CGAL's library function unmodified with only a simple wrapper function.

Comment: @Thanks marcog, a related question: is there any other algorithm that does this? Preferably it should be found in existing computational geometry libraty.

Comment: @Ngu I'm not aware of any that'll be as efficient. Your added condition is not making it much easier to solve. Even if you tried adapting bentley-otterman, you'd still have to process events when lines from the same set intersect to keep them sorted in y.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Bentley-Ottmann algorithm can be extended to do this, along with other methods.

In literature, the task you described along the lines of **reporting intersections between red and blue lines**.

Here is a paper extending B-O sweep to an optimal algorithm.
http://www.cs.unc.edu/~snoeyink/demos/rbseg/jcdcg25.pdf

I would disagree with @marcog's claim about complexity. The paper linked claims optimal time of O(n log(n+k)), if you filter the intersections, you will have to perform a B-O sweep on all lines, and it would be ((n+k) log n).

There are other similar algorithms which may not require complex data-structures http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/pdf/palazzi93counting.pdf

For fewer edges and fewer intersections between edges, the solution in @marcog's answer *might* work well. (Here is an example from CGAL http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/Arrangement_on_surface_2_2consolidated_curve_data_8cpp-example.html).

If you need to process complex polygons (GIS data etc.) or need a general algorithm, this class of algorithms might be worth while.

Answer (score 0):

Where Bentley-Ottman keeps a tree of line segments ordered by their current vertical position, couldn't you keep *two* trees, one each for groups A and B? Then where the original algorithm checks the neighbors above and below the current point, you'd check the A-neighbor above against the B-neighbor below, and vice versa.

This is based on a quick skim of the Wikipedia article; I haven't written much geometrical code in the past decade.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer for completeness, even though it may not be the most efficient method for 2 dimensions.

In 3D graphics its common to 2 KD-trees, which can be used to detect all overlapping nodes (can be used for boolean operations on geometry).

Working example (C code).
https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/BLI_kdopbvh.c;3b4a8f1cfa7339f3db9ddd4a7974b8cc30d7ff0b$1089

If there are many small segments (such as the path of a hand drawn line), this will be reasonably efficient. However if there are many long edges *(think pickup-sticks)*... this will perform badly, and you would want to split leaf nodes in the BVH tree to get better performance. However if thats the case, its probably better to use a different method as suggested in other answers.